# How do I create a big multiplayer world in UDK?

Tags: mmo, multiplayer, terrain-rendering, udk, terrain

I want to create a big multiplayer world in UDK and I'm having a few difficulties.

1. I created the biggest terrain possible but then any terrain related action I do takes forever. However, I've seen videos of people make same size terrain and working without a problem. My pc is strong enough, so maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.
2. I want to make it even bigger then the biggest terrain size, so I was thinking of doing level streaming but then I read that streaming is working server side which means if I have a player on every terrain all terrains will still be loaded and I want to save as much memory possible so it will work well online.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 3):

1) You need to think about a streaming solution, stream in and out parts of your level as you require them (radial streaming, streaming volumes, etc...)

2) I think you need to rethink your plan.  Unreal isn't made to support the MMO type of games (it's one of your tags).

Comment: 1)i know about level streaming but i want to do it with big level so it will be even bigger                                           2)the future plan is an mmo but i want to use udk to make some sort of demo to test things out                                          and there is an mmo made with UE3 which is APB its not open world like i want but its still made of very big maps

Comment: also DC universe is build with UE3 and it looks open world (haven't acutely played it)

Comment: It's not because a team did it that it's a good idea.  The Unreal Engine is not meant to process hundreds of pawns, so without lots changes, it's simply not the best decision to go with this engine.  I can't get into details because of NDAs, but I would advise you reconsider the engine if you plan on doing a MMO.

Comment: how about cryenigne then? do youknow if its meant for that kind of games? im pretty sure i sa a couple open world games using cryenigne

Comment: There is a major difference between open world and MMO!  Also, what is the background of your team?  What is your budget?  It might affect which engine to use!

Comment: dosnt meter right now i only want to do open world simulation for testing just to see how it works and if serves my pourpse so i want an engine that free (like udk or crytek sdk) just to test rthings out

Comment: I agree with everyone here, you really need a custom solution instead of trying to squeeze blood from a stone.  UE3 is a pretty good stone, and there are a few other stones out there, but stones just aren't born to bleed.

Answer (score -3):

cryengine3 is an automatic open world sandbox editor and can make the world open for you. I know where you are coming from and what kinda gameplay you have in mind coz i also have the same desire to make open world games. If you wanna use cryengine3 pls do so to make it possible for you to achieve your dream but even though there are good sides to cryengine, there are also the bad sides. The bad sides are that until now the crydev ( cryengine ) is still a baby in providing you or anyone else with tutorials and info about the depth of the engine, but i am sure as years pass by the community will develop and grow so that anyone can reach out for help and gain knowledge by just searching and practicing them out, but for now it is a difficult task to do so. I myself used the cryengine as soon as it came out, but came towards many blocks and i couldnt search for any help for all those small needs, But then i quickly changed my engine and chose to use the unreal engine  3. Why?, well first of all the unreal engine ( UDK ) has a vast amount of resource for the community and people of interest like you and me and even though it there is no info out there which teaches us how to make an mmo open world game ( which is strange ), i also agree with you that there are developers out there who has made great MMO RPG games using UDK, so guess its a secret. I believe that one day, some one will put a tutorial about making a open world Game with UDK and this will solve everyones problem and even if no one puts it out there for us to read, i am sure that one day UDK will update and suddenly it will have kismats or something else which will allow us to easily create a MMO type game just like what cryengine is doing right now.  So my suggestion and recommendation is to study the UDK and just hold on until some kind of resource about making MMO games will be found by you in the search engine or it will be given to you in a free update.

Comment: That's a pretty large stream of consciousness, but not a good answer.

Comment: @Byte56 more like a large stream of gibberish.